# Convert the output of the "lsque -q" command

Tags: ksh, aix, printing

There is a list of printers in a file:

```
0:root@SERVER:/root #cat printernames.txt
PRINTQ1
PRINTQ2
PRINTQ3
...
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

And there is a command that produces this output (info about given printers, for example the PRINTQ1, the lines that have = could be in a different order than this):

```
0:root@SERVER:/root #lsque -q PRINTQ1
PRINTQ1:
    device = PRINTQ1.dev
    host = AL1
    l_statfilter = /usr/lib/lpd/aixlong
    rq = LPT1_PASSTHRU
    s_statfilter = /usr/lib/lpd/aixshort
    up = TRUE
0:root@SERVER:/root #
```

We need the output of the `lsque -q PRINTERNAME` command in the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/piomisc_base mkpq_other  -q"PRINTQ1" -d "PRINTQ1.dev" \
  -b"/usr/lpd/rembak" -u"TRUE" -h"PRINTQ1" -r"PRINTQ1" \
  -s"/usr/lib/lpd/aixshort" -l"/usr/lib/lpd/aixlong"
```

**Question**: how can we generate the piomisc_base commands from the output of the lsque command? Just puting the values to the right place to the piomisc_base.

So basically creating piomisc_base commands that we will later run (on another server).

`-b"/usr/lpd/rembak"` -> this is constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ksh93`:

```
#!/bin/ksh -e

queue="$1"

typeset $( lsque -q "$queue" | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ //g' )

/usr/sbin/piomisc_base mkpq_other \
    -q"$queue" \
    -d "$device" \
    -b"/usr/lpd/rembak" \
    -u"$up" \
    -h"$queue" \
    -r"$queue" \
    -s"$s_statfilter" \
    -l"$l_statfilter"
```

The queue is taken from the command line and saved in the variable `queue`.  This value is then used with `lsque` to get the output that you show in the question.  Thes `sed` command strips off the first line of this output and removes all spaces.

The result of the above operation is passed to `typeset` which will simply carry out the assignments of values to the variables in the output.

These variables are then used in the call to `piomisc_base`.